# What are the system requirements for the Elder Scrolls: Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

From the press footage and trailers so far, Skyrim looks to be pretty graphics intensive, and I'm worried my computer won't be able to handle it.

Have the official system requirements been released yet? If so, what are they?

Comment: the fact that it's multiplatform (like drake points out) is an important fact to remember...for such games, the max resolution that the developers typically put their time into is 1920x1080 (or variances thereof).  You should also keep in mind that trailers are of course intended to impress....just because they ran a test run on Deep Thought doesn't mean you won't be able to run it on lesser settings on a current-gen or last-gen PC.

Comment: I think it's far too early for this question. The game isn't set to launch for another two months.

Comment: I've clocked up about 70 hours playing on an old Sony Vaio with a Core Duo 1.86ghz, 2Gb ram, and a Nvidia 8400M GT. I get constant 25-30fps outside, up to 40fps indoor, playing on low settings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally Bethesda has released the official requirements: http://www.bethblog.com/index.php/2011/10/25/skyrim-system-requirements-announced/

> **Recommended Specs**
>    - Windows 7/Vista/XP PC (32 or 64 bit)
>    - Processor: Quad-core Intel or AMD CPU
>    - 4GB System RAM
>    - 6GB free HDD space
>    - DirectX 9 compatible NVIDIA or AMD ATI video card with 1GB of RAM (Nvidia GeForce GTX 260 or higher; ATI Radeon 4890 or higher)
>    - DirectX compatible sound card
>    - Internet access for Steam activation
>
> **Minimum Specs**
>    - Windows 7/Vista/XP PC (32 or 64 bit)
>    - Processor: Dual Core 2.0GHz or equivalent processor
>    - 2GB System RAM
>    - 6GB free HDD Space
>    - Direct X 9 compliant video card with 512 MB of RAM
>    - DirectX compatible sound card
>    - Internet access for Steam activation

Comment: I I I so excited. I so excited. Ev'rybody's looking forward to the 11th.

Comment: I can't wait till it goes on steam sale for $19.99. Then I'll snag it. :-)

Comment: I'm sad that no-one seems to have linked @Coomie's comment to Rebecca Black.

Answer (score 5):

Supposedly the system requirements will be released in October, however, there are a number of sites that have guessed at what they will be. This may give you a starting point.

http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=625&game=The%20Elder%20Scrolls%20V
Intel CPU - Celeron E3300 Dual-Core 2.5GHz
AMD CPU - Athlon II X2 240
Nvidia GFX Card - GeForce GT 420
ATI GFX Card - Radeon HD 5670 512MB 
RAM (Memory) - 4 GB
Hard Disk Space - 10 GB
Direct X - 9

http://www.skyrimportal.com/skyrim-system-requirements
CPU: Core 2 Duo/Athlon X2 or better
 RAM: 1.5GB
 Video Card: NVIDIA 7800 Series, ATI Radeon 1800 Series or better
 VRAM: 512MB of Graphics Memory
 Storage: 12GB
 Sound Card: DirectX 9.0c Compatible
 ODD: DVD-ROM
 DirectX: DX9.0c

http://www.systemrequirements.in/system-requirements-for-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim.html
Minimum System Requirements
 * OS: Windows XP, Vista or Windows 7
 * CPU: Core 2 Duo 2.0 GHz or Althon X2 2.0 GHz
 * RAM: 3 GB
 * HDD: 15 GB
 * Graphics: 512 MB card
 * Sound Card: DirectX 9 Compatible
 * DirectX: Version 9.0c

Recommended System Requirements
 * OS: Windows XP, Vista or Windows 7
 * CPU: Core 2 Quad 3 GHz
 * RAM: 3 GB
 * HDD: 15 GB free disk space
 * Graphics: 512 MB Graphics Memory
 * Sound Card: DirectX 9 Compatible
 * DirectX: Version 9.0c

Supported Graphics Cards:
Minimum – 8800 GT
Recommanded – Geforce GTX 460/Radeon 5850